# lost virtualenv display to the left of bash prompt

Tags: ubuntu, bash, bash-scripting, bashrc, virtualenv

I added thy Holy prompt to display my current branch so I never push to master. We all use it and it works, but I am no-longer seeing what virtualenv I'm using at the moment, which is a hassle. Based on this prompt: is there a simple way to regain my `(mysite-env)` style virtualenv display?

```
### Git prompt.
# Configure colors, if available.
if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
c_reset='\[\e[0m\]'
c_user='\[\033[1;33m\]'
c_path='\[\e[0;33m\]'
c_git_clean='\[\e[0;36m\]'
c_git_dirty='\[\e[0;35m\]'
else
c_reset=
c_user=
c_path=
c_git_clean=
c_git_dirty=
fi

# Function to assemble the Git part of our prompt.
git_prompt ()
{
if ! git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1; then
return 0
fi

git_branch=$(git branch 2>/dev/null| sed -n '/^\*/s/^\* //p')

if git diff --quiet 2>/dev/null >&2; then
git_color="$c_git_clean"
else
git_color="$c_git_dirty"
fi

echo " [$git_color$git_branch${c_reset}]"
}

# Thy holy prompt.
PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="${c_user}\u${c_reset}@${c_user}\h${c_reset}:${c_path}\w${c_reset}$(git_prompt)\$ "'
### End git prompt.
```

I have a venv turned on:

```
cchilders@worklaptop:~/work_projects/oursite [ckc/fix-checkbox-AMA-1234]$
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This dude's creation is sufficient, I'm studying it now:

https://gist.github.com/miki725/9783474